# Django update ViewSet

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, imagefield

Currently I am developing a image gallery django project. The user can upload images, and later upload a 'result' to each of the images.
I know that I have to override the update(...) function, but I think I need help here with the Base64ImageFiled.

Step by step:

1. User uploads image (result = null)
2. Image gets stored in cloud
3. User uploads result to a specified image (need help here)

Here is my current structure:

```
class Image(models.Model):
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
  result = models.ImageField(upload_to='results')

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  project = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
  image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=False)
  result = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=False, required=False)

class ProjectImagesViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
  queryset = Image.objects.select_related('project').all()
  serializer_class = ImageSerializer

  def list(self, request, project_pk=None):
    queryset = self.queryset.filter( project__name = project_pk)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

  def update(self, request, pk=None, project_pk=None):
    print(request.data['result'])
    ???
```

Answer (score 11):

Django Rest Framework convention is to use partial_update instead of update (PATCH request method). If you will send PATCH request with image to the same url as for retrieve [url](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#api-guide) is should get updated. if you require  additional features on update then you can define:

```
class ProjectImagesViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    #.....
    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = self.get_object()
            serializer = self.serialize(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            #.... Your code ....
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

**EDIT:**
Try those changes:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
    image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=False)
    result = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Image


class ProjectImagesViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.select_related('project').all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def list(self, request, project_pk=None):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(project__name=project_pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk=None, project_pk=None):
        print(request.data['result'])

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        serializer = self.serializer_class(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I am getting the following error: AttributeError: type object 'ImageSerializer' has no attribute 'serialize'

Comment: which version of DRF are you using ?